# JMeter not detecting jar added to lib folder or classpath

Tags: java, mongodb, jmeter, load-testing

Trying to query MongoDb through JMeter. I've downloaded the `mongodb-driver-sync-4.2.3.jar` from maven and copied it into `lib` and `lib/ext` folders.

My JSR223Sampler code is basically a copy paste of Mongo's quickstart code:

```
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

def connectionString = new ConnectionString("CONNECTION_STRING");
def settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
        .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
        .build();
def mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
def database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
```

But I keep getting the error saying the imports are failing:

```
Script2.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.mongodb.ConnectionString
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
   ^

Script2.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
   ^

2 errors

javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script2.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.mongodb.ConnectionString
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
   ^

Script2.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
```

What am I missing? How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`lib/ext` folder is for JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), MongoDB driver should go to "lib" folder only
2. You **will need to restart JMeter** in order to pick up the .jar.
3. `mongodb-driver-sync-4.2.3.jar` per se doesn't provide [com.mongodb.ConnectionString](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.html), the class lives in [mongodb-driver-core-4.2.3.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.2.3)
4. Depending on what you will be doing after opening the connection you might also need to have [bson-4.2.3.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/bson/4.2.3) in JMeter classpath

More information: [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter)